# SVG oval path scaling proportionally with window along both axes for circular "marquee"

Tags: css, svg

I'm trying to create an oval SVG path that I want to use as an animated text path similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/48354097/10727821 in order to create a sort of circular "marquee" that always takes full width and height of the browser window, ignoring the aspect ratio.

I guess the issue is that my `<ellipse>` is describing a perfect circle, whereas I'd want it to be more flexible than that – but I don't really know how I'd do that…

```css
.ellipse {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  svg {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
  ellipse {
    fill: #333;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="ellipse">
<svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<ellipse cx="500" cy="500" rx="500" ry="500"/>
</svg>
</div>
```

expected output would be something like this:
[image: sketch of responsive ellipse text]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you need. I'm recalculating the viewBox of the svg element and the d path proportional to the `wrap.clientWidth` and the `wrap.clientHeight` where `wrap` is the wrapping div `<div id="wrap">`.

```js
function Init(){
  let w = wrap.clientWidth;
  let h = wrap.clientHeight;
  ellipse.setAttributeNS(null,"viewBox",`0 0 ${w}  ${h}`);
  let d = `M${w/10},${h/2}A${4*w/10},${4*h/10} 0 0 0 ${9*w/10} ${5*h/10} A${4*w/10},${4*h/10} 0 0 0 ${w/10} ${5*h/10}`

thePath.setAttributeNS(null,"d", d)
}


window.setTimeout(function() {
  Init();
  window.addEventListener('resize', Init, false);
}, 15);
```

```css
#wrap{width:100vw; height:100vh}
  svg {
    background:#eee;
  }
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
<svg id="ellipse" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" preserveAspectRatio="none">  
<path id="thePath" fill="gold" d="M100,500A400,400 0 0 0 900 500 A400,400 0 0 0 100 500"  />
  
  
   <text stroke="#000000" font-size="20">
      <textPath xlink:href="#thePath" dy="5">
            svg oval path scaling proportionally with window along both axes for circular svg oval path scaling proportionally with window along both axes for circular svg oval path scaling proportionally with window along both axes for circular
      </textPath>
    </text>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it's working like a charm! Do you have a suggestion how I could rotate the text kind of "marquee-like" around the path like in the example I provided?

Comment: For a marquee-like effect please take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53052158/write-text-on-shape-path/53052934#53052934 If this doesn't work for you please ask this as a different question. I'll be glad to help.

Comment: thank you for the answer – I have posted another follow-up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56041826/10727821