# Move Text on a patch

Tags: svg, text, move, patch

I have seen this effect somewhere that was made using Lottie Files (Image attached) I tried to use a Codepen file and edit that to recreate it instead of using Lottie files since they are heavy.

But when the characters reach the endpoint of the SVG patch, they overlap each other but I want them to move infinitely. Any help would be useful!
Thanks in advance

Codepen Link:

```js
Splitting({
    whitespace: true
})
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata:700");

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: black;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    color: white;
}

h2 {
    font-family: Inconsolata, monospace;
    font-size: 1.2vw;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.char {
    // --i: calc(50% / var(--char-total));
    --offset: calc(var(--char-index) * 1rem);
    offset-path: path('M83.6,128.5C31.6,195.5,0,283.6,0,380,0,589.9,149.5,760,333.8,760S667.6,589.9,667.6,380,518.2,0,333.8,0C234.2,0,144.7,49.7,83.6,128.5');
    offset-distance: var(--offset);
    position: absolute;
    animation: move 20000ms infinite alternate forwards var(--delay, 0ms);
}

h2 {
    &:nth-child(2) {
        color: white;
        
        .char {
            --delay: calc(var(--char-index) * 30ms);
        }
    }
}

@keyframes move {
    100% {
        // --i: 2rem;
        offset-distance: calc(var(--offset) + 150rem);
    }
    0%
    {
        
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/splitting@1.0.6/dist/splitting.min.js"></script>
<h2 data-splitting> THE PLACEHOLDER TEXT IS JUST FOR FUN - TAKE THE LIFE EASY AND BE BRAVE -  THE PLACEHOLDER TEXT IS JUST FOR FUN -  </h2>
```

Screenshot of the Lottie file:
[image: Screenshot of the Lottie file]

Comment: Please take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56041826/animate-marquee-on-svg-curve/56042973#56042973

Comment: The effect is not smooth! Do you think there is a way to improve it?