# Is it possible to infinitely repeat the animation of a SVG text path?

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm able to make text crawl around a closed SVG path but unable to make the text *continue* to crawl past its starting point. I'd like the text to crawl infinitely around the path..

**Is this infinite animation possible using `<textPath>` element and `startOffset` attribute?**

You can see what I'm trying to achieve in [this video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geCZQ.jpg). I'm using JavaScript to increment the `startOffset` value. The text 'hides' once it hits the original starting point (`startOffset="0"`).

I'd like to use an SVG with real text (as opposed to a sequence or film) as the shape will (eventually) dynamically change depending on the viewer's viewport size.

```js
const textPath = document.querySelector("#text-path");

let increment = 0;

window.setInterval(function () {
  increment += 1;
  textPath.setAttribute("startOffset", + increment);
}, 1);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans:wght@900&display=swap');

body {
  margin: 5rem;
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
}

text {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

svg {
  /* Needed to show text that goes beyond viewBox */
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<svg width="440" height="440" viewBox="0 0 440 440" fill="transparent" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M40 0.5H400C421.815 0.5 439.5 18.1848 439.5 40V400C439.5 421.815 421.815 439.5 400 439.5H40C18.1847 439.5 0.5 421.815 0.5 400V40C0.5 18.1847 18.1848 0.5 40 0.5Z" id="number-one" stroke="transparent" />
  <text width="100%" fill="black" >
      <textPath alignment-baseline="top" xlink:href="#number-one" id="text-path" startOffset="0">Number one. Number one. Number one. Number one. Number one. Number one. Number one. Number one. Number one.</textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: I've created a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) for you. This way users don't have to go to an external sites and they can more easily recreate the snippet. Please edit the snippet if anything is wrong.

Comment: Please take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56041826/animate-marquee-on-svg-curve/56042973#56042973

Comment: Thanks @enxaneta. That's exactly what I was looking for, just worded in a way that I couldn't find on a search. Unfortunately the performance of this technique turns out to be too slow for my real-world use, even with performant techniques like `requestAnimationFrame`. Curious if you think a WebGL approach ([example](https://spacetypegenerator.com)) would be better in that case. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `animate` element and `repeatCount` attribute

```
<animate attributeName="startOffset" from="0%" to ="100%" begin="0s" dur="20s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animate

```js
const textPath = document.querySelector("#text-path");
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans:wght@900&display=swap');
body {
  margin: 5rem;
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
}

text {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

svg {
  /* Needed to show text that goes beyond viewBox */
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<svg width="440" height="440" viewBox="0 0 440 440" fill="transparent" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M40 0.5H400C421.815 0.5 439.5 18.1848 439.5 40V400C439.5 421.815 421.815 439.5 400 439.5H40C18.1847 439.5 0.5 421.815 0.5 400V40C0.5 18.1847 18.1848 0.5 40 0.5Z" id="number-one" stroke="transparent" />
  <text width="100%" fill="black" >
      <textPath alignment-baseline="top" xlink:href="#number-one" id="text-path" startOffset="0">Number one. Number one. Number one. Number one. Number one. Number one. Number one. Number one. Number one.
          <animate attributeName="startOffset" from="0%" to ="100%" begin="0s" dur="20s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
      </textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: This is a nicer way to animate the `startOffset` but it doesn't solve the problem of text hiding once it hits its starting point. I.e. it has the same problem as my original code. Thanks anyway