# Loop SVG text animation around rectangle path

Tags: javascript, animation, svg

I am using SVG to animate text around the path of a rounded rectangle. The idea is to have a stream of text that is constantly moving around the rectangle.

[Here's an example of the rectangle animation in this tutorial video for After Effects](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c5Iz5ma1RD8)

But when closing the SVG path for the text, the animation does not run at all and if I leave the path open the text disappears as it reaches the end as in this code snippet:

```css
html, body {
  background: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container {
  widht: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.svgwave {
  margin-left: calc(50% - 150px);
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
            <svg class="svgwave" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="301" height="301" viewBox="0 0 301 301" style="width:auto; height: auto; overflow: visible;">
                <path id="wavepath" d="M145.5 301.5H13C6.09645 301.5 0.5 295.904 0.5 289V13C0.5 6.09645 6.09644 0.5 13 0.5H289C295.904 0.5 301.5 6.09644 301.5 13V289C301.5 295.904 295.904 301.5 289 301.5H156.5" style="fill: transparent; stroke: transparent; stroke-width: 1px;"></path>

                <foreignObject x='6' y='6' width='300px' height='300px'>
                    <div
                    style="width: 282px; height: 282px;
                            border-radius: 8px;
                            background-size: contain;
                            border: 4px solid white;
                            display:inline-block; "
                    ></div>
                </foreignObject>
                <text text-anchor="middle" style="text-transform: uppercase; font-family: Arial; font-size: 20px; fill: white;">
                    <textPath style=" fill-opacity: 1" href="#wavepath" side="left" startOffset="0%">
                    <animate attributeName="startOffset" from="30%" to="42%" begin="0s" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
                    First <tspan style="fill: #DED279;">Second</tspan> 
                    First <tspan style="fill: #DED279;">Second</tspan> 
                    First <tspan style="fill: #DED279;">Second</tspan> 
                    First <tspan style="fill: #DED279;">Second</tspan> 
                    First <tspan style="fill: #DED279;">Second</tspan> 
                    First <tspan style="fill: #DED279;">Second</tspan> 
                    First <tspan style="fill: #DED279;">Second</tspan> 
                    First <tspan style="fill: #DED279;">Second</tspan> 
                    First <tspan style="fill: #DED279;">Second</tspan> 
                    First <tspan style="fill: #DED279;">Second</tspan> 
                    First <tspan style="fill: #DED279;">Second</tspan> 
                    First <tspan style="fill: #DED279;">Second</tspan> 
                    </textPath>
                </text>
            </svg>

        </div>
```

- What would be the best way to achieve this animation using SVG?
- Would there be any alternative way to achieve this with Javascript?

Comment: Like this? http://srufaculty.sru.edu/david.dailey/svg/newstuff/textpath1.svg

Comment: Thanks for the comment @RobertLongson but something more along the lines of this [animation](https://gifyu.com/image/SsK5b). At the end, the animation does not comes back, text end up disappearing

Comment: Please take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56041826/animate-marquee-on-svg-curve/56042973#56042973

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you extend the path and add textLength settings to make sure that the text wraps perfectly - and tweak a few other things you can get this to look better. Still has a tiny seam jitter, but it's not that noticeable.

```css
html, body {
  background: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container {
  widht: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.svgwave {
  margin-left: calc(50% - 150px);
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
            <svg class="svgwave" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="301" height="301" viewBox="0 0 301 301" style="width:auto; height: auto; overflow: visible;">
                <path id="wavepath" d="M145.5 301.5H13C6.09645 301.5 0.5 295.904 0.5 289V13C0.5 6.09645 6.09644 0.5 13 0.5H289C295.904 0.5 301.5 6.09644 301.5 13V289C301.5 295.904 295.904 301.5 289 301.5H156.5 H13C6.09645 301.5 0.5 295.904 0.5 289V13C0.5 6.09645 6.09644 0.5 13 0.5H289C295.904 0.5 301.5 6.09644 301.5 13V289C301.5 295.904 295.904 301.5 289 301.5H156.5 H13C6.09645 301.5 0.5 295.904 0.5 289V13C0.5 6.09645 6.09644 0.5 13 0.5H289C295.904 0.5 301.5 6.09644 301.5 13V289C301.5 295.904 295.904 301.5 289 301.5H156.5 H13C6.09645 301.5 0.5 295.904 0.5 289V13C0.5 6.09645 6.09644 0.5 13 0.5H289C295.904 0.5 301.5 6.09644 301.5 13V289C301.5 295.904 295.904 301.5 289 301.5H156.5" style="fill: transparent; stroke: transparent; stroke-width: 1px;" ></path>

                <foreignObject x='6' y='6' width='300px' height='300px'>
                    <div
                    style="width: 282px; height: 282px;
                            border-radius: 8px;
                            background-size: contain;
                            border: 4px solid white;
                            display:inline-block; "
                    ></div>
                </foreignObject>
                <text text-anchor="left" style="text-transform: uppercase; font-family: Arial; font-size: 20px; fill: white;">
                    <textPath style=" fill-opacity: 1" href="#wavepath" side="left" startOffset="0%" textLength="1175">
                    <animate attributeName="startOffset" from="20%" to="42%" begin="0s" dur="12s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
                    First <tspan style="fill: #DED279;">Second</tspan> 
                    First <tspan style="fill: #DED279;">Second</tspan> 
                    First <tspan style="fill: #DED279;">Second</tspan> 
                    First <tspan style="fill: #DED279;">Second</tspan> 
                    First <tspan style="fill: #DED279;">Second</tspan> 
                    First <tspan style="fill: #DED279;">Second</tspan> 
                    First <tspan style="fill: #DED279;">Second</tspan> 
                    First <tspan style="fill: #DED279;">Second</tspan> 
                    </textPath>
                </text>
            </svg>
```

Comment: Thanks that is perfect! It really answers my question. I'll give it a try with other text to see if there is any way to make it programmatically.