SVG Path with text, infinite animation marquee style
Is it possible to have a SVG animation working as a marquee? I mean with no blank space.
At the moment looks like this


<svg viewBox="0 0 2880 204" style="enable-background:new 0 0 2880 204;" xml:space="preserve">
  <style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:none;stroke:white;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
  </style>
  <g>
    <path id="textPathCurve" class="st0" d="M-117,38.1c126.4,0,126.4,102,252.8,102c126.4,0,126.4-102,252.8-102c126.4,0,126.4,102,252.8,102
      c126.4,0,126.4-102,252.8-102c126.4,0,126.4,102,252.8,102s126.4-102,252.8-102c126.4,0,126.4,102,252.8,102s126.4-102,252.8-102
      c126.4,0,126.4,102,252.8,102c126.4,0,126.4-102,252.8-102c126.4,0,126.4,102,252.8,102c126.4,0,126.4-102,252.8-102
      s126.4,102,252.8,102"/>
    <text font-family="Arial" font-size="18" fill="black" letter-spacing="1px">
      <textPath href="#textPathCurve">
        MARQUEES TITLE MARQUEES TITLE MARQUEES TITLE MARQUEES TITLE MARQUEES TITLE MARQUEES TITLE MARQUEES TITLE MARQUEES TITLE MARQUEES TITLE MARQUEES TITLE MARQUEES TITLE MARQUEES TITLE MARQUEES TITLE MARQUEES TITLE MARQUEES TITLE MARQUEES TITLE  
        <animate attributeName="startOffset" from="00%" to="100%" begin="0s" dur="30s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
      </textPath>
    </text>
  </g>
</svg>



Thanks
I tried the SVG way, made it work with a Marquee library obviously, but then I can't make it work over a path.

please take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56041826/animate-marquee-on-svg-curve/56042973#56042973
